# Order of evaluation in Clojure recursion

Tags: clojure

SPOILER ALERT: This question refers to a 4clojure.com question. If you're a Clojure newbie like me, you probably want to try it by yourself first.

I answered this question (#68) successfully, but only after making a mistake which I'm still not sure why is wrong.

Here's the question:

```
(= __
  (loop [x 5
         result []]
    (if (> x 0)
      (recur (dec x) (conj result (+ 2 x)))
      result)))
```

My initial answer was `[6 5 4 3 2]` while the accepted answer is `[7 6 5 4 3]`. 
I don't totally grok it, because `(dec x)` *precedes* `(conj result (+ 2 x))`, and they're both equally nested in the loop. I'd thought that because the decrement seems to happen before the conjoin, the result vector would begin with a decremented x plus two. But it's not happening that way. This is clearly something very basic, but perhaps someone might explain it what's going on? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables in clojure and immutable (mostly, anyway). `(dec x)` does not actually decrease `x` in the current scope. It *returns* the result of `(dec x)`, which is then used as an argument to recur, which you can treat as another call of the `loop` "function". So `x` is not changed in this scope. `(conj result (+ 2 x))` uses the same variable `x` with the same old value.